# How do I connect to Google Cloud Storage from a Google App Engine PHP script?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to write to a file in a Google Cloud Storage bucket from my App Engine using PHP. I've followed the documentation for setting up a bucket and accessing it via PHP:

- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/index#Prerequisites
- https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/

I've added the app engine's Service Account Name as an owner of the bucket in question, but when I attempt to run something like the following:

```
$fp = fopen('gs://[bucket-name]/log/log.txt', 'a+');
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  fopen(gs://[bucket-name]/log.txt): failed to open stream: 
"\google\appengine\ext\cloud_storage_streams\CloudStorageStreamWrapper::stream_open" 
call failed in /[myfile.php] on line 33
```

`[bucket-name]` is just a placeholder, I'm using the correct bucket name. Am I missing something?

Comment: FWIW, I also read the post @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294785/how-to-use-google-cloud-storage-for-php?rq=1 and tried to find alternate App Engine email identifiers to give ownership of the bucket to, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a+` is not a valid mode for opening a GCS file. Objects in GCS can't be appended to. They can only be overwritten. You can find the valid modes here:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/php/sdk/google/appengine/ext/cloud_storage_streams/CloudStorageStreamWrapper.php?spec=svn404&r=400#56

Comment: That was it. Changing the write mode to `'w'` allows the stream to work properly. I'm now having a problem with the `is_resource($fp)` function and Google Cloud Storage where it always return false, perhaps that's related. I'll play with it when I have the time. Thanks for your help!